# ImportError: libcudnn.so.7 tensorlfow (path setting doesnt work}

Tags: tensorflow

I am getting this error tried all the fixes please help

```
 import tensorflow as tf
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: libcudnn.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

did fixes as recommneded led me here updated path after installing Cuda 5.1
[ImportError: libcudnn when running a TensorFlow program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41991101)

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64"
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda

my paths
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64
echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

[Tensorflow: ImportError: libcudnn.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51019509/tensorflow-importerror-libcudnn-so-7-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such)

did the source bash
still error is there. Did all available fixes.

thanks

Comment: It seems that you need [`cuDNN Library for Linux`](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download)

Comment: I have that? Install is fine for CUDA I set path... It runs fine in CPU not in GPU... Is there a better alternative for using your GPU?

Comment: `cuDNN` installed separately, `CUDA` installer dont contain `cuDNN`

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#software_requirements

Comment: Issue might be corrupted symlinks, create new one for CUDA installation. Take a look at similar issue comment https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20271#issuecomment-643296453. Thanks